# Is there an English translation of Nicolas de la Mare's 1722 work "Traité de la Police"?

Tags: england, france, book, scotland, police

Most places on the Internet (or maybe just the sites with the best SEO) put the origins of Western policing with Scotland Yard. For example, [this article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2020/07/20/the-invention-of-the-police#:%7E:text=a%20civil%20force%20charged%20with%20deterring%20crime%2C%20came%20to%20the%20United%20States%20from%20England) says policing came to the U.S. via England, ignoring that those origins in England, actually stem from policing in Scotland. [This video](https://youtu.be/n7Rm3tuMFTI?t=184) also says policing started in 1829 in England. Now, to be sure, Scotland Yard did revolutionize crime-fighting, however they were building upon well over a century of policing experience, including de la Mare's work, completed over a century before Scotland Yard was founded.

Now, I understand there are many differences between policing in France, and even policing in Scotland pre-1829. This is the reason for my question. I believe this would be a very good primary source for how policing was done back then, and, given its importance, I imagine (maybe, "hope" is a better word here) *someone* has translated it to English. Further, I hope that translation was done long enough ago that it is in the public domain. But, I will accept any English translation. I cannot find the book to buy anywhere, I can't find it on WorldCat, and I can't find a digital copy anywhere. Can someone help me find an English translation?

***Note: I know someone will complain about the fluff at the beginning asking why I didn't simply ask for the translation and that's all. The reason I added the beginning bit is because in "How to ask a good question", it says to make it relevant to as many people as possible. This beginning bit makes it relevant to a large number of people who believe that policing started with Scotland Yard, or was a purely English invention.

Comment: I cannot find an English translation of de la Mare's work. All references in the literature seem to be to the original work, and I cannot find a translation at any book seller. As far as I am concerned you are providing excellent context for the question, not fluff. Another work you may be interested is this German book: Johann Heinrich Gottlob von Justi, "Grundsätze der Policey-Wissenschaften," 1756  ([scan of second edition of 1759](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb10766847?page=5)). I know there is a Spanish translation (1784) of it, but don't know of an English translation.

Comment: Just as an aside: The importance of the creation of the Metropolitan Police in London in 1829 isn't that it invented policing (because it didn't) but that it became the blueprint for modern organised, professional policing within the anglosphere. In the same way that the Wright Brothers didn't invent concept of the aircraft, they just came up with a design that solved the problems of heavier than air, controlled, powered flight which others then copied.

Comment: I was going to suggest getting the Archive.org copy as full text and then translating that to English...but the work appears to be in 4 volumes, the first of which is over a thousand pages, so that's not likely to be practical.

Comment: @njuffa Man, you're killing me. Now there's another book I want translated. Thank you for that. Anybody know how much it would cost to have a book translated? Any chance there are people that would do it for free? I mean, couldn't they copyright the translation and sell it? Both of these books seem like important books in the history of policing that is obviously missing from the English literature on this issue. This is exactly  how I was NOT wanting this question to go. lol

Comment: @SteveBird I understand why people hold such reverence for the LMP. The problem is, it would seem in most literature on the subject, the LMP seems to spring up out of nowhere and solve an incredibly complex problem. The issue with this narrative is that ignores the pioneering work doing by the River Thames Police in 1800, Glasgow Police in 1795/9, apparently work done by the Germans, and obviously the French. LMP was the end product of more than 100 years of police evolution, not the beginning. That was my point. It leaves out crucial information. But, no doubt the Brits elevated the game.

Comment: @JimmyG. At a cost of $25 to $60 per translated page (outdated language variant; specialized subject matter), you would be looking at a serious chunk of money for a professional translation. I don't think crowdsourcing would work. Taking some time to learn relevant languages might be a better option if you plan to pursue research in European history. Unfortunately foreign language requirements at American universities have largely been watered down or even abolished.

Comment: In my first term of studying history (of science), a professor told us that a serious student would need a working knowledge of at least seven languages...

Comment: @JimmyG. This is not my area of expertise, but from cursory reading it seems to me that prior to the 19th century "police" encompassed all aspects of civil administration, and only later did the meaning narrow down to "the police" as the kind of enforcement and investigative organization we know today. I guess this goes to the point Steve Bird made in an earlier comment.

Comment: @JimmyG. - They needed to "elevate the game". They had the largest city in the world at that time, and the only one on Earth housing over a million souls. It seems like at that point there ought to have been some kind of qualitative state change in how order can be managed.